# Ubuntu admin session not loading after uninstall gnome shell

Tags: 12.04, gnome, uninstall

I'm having a big big issue on my Ubuntu 12.04. I wanted to uninstall gnome shell from my computer. So according to a forum (I don't remember which one), I uninstalled it from the Package Manager and then the non uninstalled packages from command line.

When I rebooted my machine, I can see the login screen. However, when typing my password, the session start loading and then go back to my login screen without any error message.

Is there a way to boot on a rescue mode or super admin mode and reinstall at least ubuntu desktop or something who could fix it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure the login manager is not just defaulting to the (now removed) session? Assuming you are still using lightdm and did not remove ALL your sessions, have you tried pressing the Ubuntu 'button' next to your login name on the screen and selecting one of the other available desktop sessions? BTW if that doesn't work, the answer to your question is yes - you can boot into the non-GUI recovery mode or even just Ctrl-Alt-F1 to get a 'virtual terminal' (text console)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally found a solution. When I uninstalled `gnome-shell`, I also accidently uninstall `gnome-panel` (gnome classic).
From the login screen, I just connnected to my accound using the terminal `ctrl`+`alt`+`F3` and then `sudo apt-get install gnome-panel`.

Worked like a charm. Thanks for your help